Superpower parser, how to parse a string with some keyword at the end and variable length prefix
I am using Superpower parser library in C#. I would like to create parser which would parse a string similar the following regexp expression:
(?'prefix'.*)(some\skeyword)

For example, from the string "This is some prefix of some keyword" I would like to get the "This is some prefix of" as a prefix.
My attempt is as follow:
        public static readonly TokenListParser<StoryToken, string> Text =
            Token.EqualTo(StoryToken.Text)
            .Select(x => x.Span.ToStringValue());

        public static readonly TokenListParser<StoryToken, string> Keyword =
            from k1 in Token.EqualToValueIgnoreCase(StoryToken.Text, "some")
            from k2 in Token.EqualToValueIgnoreCase(StoryToken.Text, "keyword")
            select "some keyword";

        public static readonly TokenListParser<StoryToken, string> TextWithKeyword =
            from prefix in Text.Many()
            from keyword in Keyword
            select string.Join(" ", prefix) + " " + keyword;

But this doesn't work. The problem is that the line:
            from prefix in Text.Many()

consumes all tokens from the input, including "some" and "keyword", and the parser fails with the error "expected "some" but end of input is encountered".
I tried to add .Try() before .Many() in that line, and tried to add .AtEnd() to the Keyword -- but that doesn't change anything.
Any ideas how I can achieve my goal with the Superpower parser?

The only way to solve this problem I found so far is to generate parsers for the fixed amount of words in the prefix, starting from 0 (no prefix) to some MAX_WORDS count. The code looks like this:
    public class TestParsers
    {
        public static readonly TokenListParser<StoryToken, string> Text =
            Token.EqualTo(StoryToken.Text)
            .Select(x => x.Span.ToStringValue());

        public static readonly TokenListParser<StoryToken, string> Keyword =
            from k1 in Token.EqualToValueIgnoreCase(StoryToken.Text, "some")
            from k2 in Token.EqualToValueIgnoreCase(StoryToken.Text, "keyword")
            select "some keyword";

        public static TokenListParser<StoryToken, (string Prefix, string Keyword)> BuildParser(int wordCount)
        {
            return 
                from prefix in Text.Repeat(wordCount)
                from keyword in Keyword
                select (string.Join(" ", prefix), keyword);
        }

        public static TokenListParser<StoryToken, (string Prefix, string Keyword)> BuildTextWithKeyword(int maxWordCount)
        {
            var parser = BuildParser(0);
            for (var i = 1; i <= maxWordCount; i++)
            {
                parser = parser.Try().Or(BuildParser(i));
            }

            return parser;
        }

        public static readonly TokenListParser<StoryToken, (string Prefix, string Keyword)> TextWithKeyword =
            BuildTextWithKeyword(10);
    }

and corresponding usage:
var storyTokenizer = StoryTokenizer.Get();
TokenList<StoryToken> tokens;

tokens = storyTokenizer.Tokenize("Some prefix some keyword");
var rv = TestParsers.TextWithKeyword.TryParse(tokens);
Console.WriteLine($"Prefix: {rv.Value.Prefix}, keyword: {rv.Value.Keyword}");

So in this code the Superpower engine tries multiple generated parsers of various prefix lengths until it manages to match the shortest possible prefix followed by the keyword.
The approach works but would be nice to find more elegant solution for the task.
